# Spring 4 binaries download

Tags: java, spring, spring-4

I haven't downloaded spring in a while. I'm investigating gradle, but don't seem to have the hang of it yet, so i want to create a new spring framework project using java, Spring 4 and ant. I can't seem to find the place to download the binaries for Spring 4.

Are they just kicking ant developers under the bus?

Comment: Use `ivy` with `ant` for accessing artifacts from maven repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maven and Gradle are the preferred ways to use Spring Framework in your project, but [dist ZIPs are still available on the official repository](http://repo.spring.io/libs-release/org/springframework/spring/4.0.0.RELEASE/).

Answer (score 9):

> Are they just kicking ant developers under the bus?

No. As Brian [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20630626/622403), distribution zips are still available at http://repo.spring.io for those who have no other option. Ant users are encouraged to integrate Ivy into their build scripts to manage dependencies so that they will not need these dist zips. Ivy is capable of working against Maven-compatible artifact repositories to provide the same transitive dependency management benefits as Maven and Gradle do. Ant is a perfectly fine build solution for many folks, and we expect it will continue to be for some time. However, manually managing dependencies, i.e. downloading dist zips, storing jars on a network drive or checking them into source control is widely understood in the industry as a problematic approach.

We believe that the majority of Spring users are already using transitive dependency management solutions in one form or another. We continue to provide dist zips for those who have not yet been able to adopt this practice, but to be clear, it is intentional that we have not given those dist zips the first-class treatment on spring.io that they once had on springsource.org, because working with dist zips is simply an inferior way to manage an application's dependencies.

Spring is about helping application development teams eliminate unnecessary complexity. There are few things that can make developing an application more complex and frustrating than the "jar hell" that ensues from manual dependency management. Here are but a few examples of why this can be so painful:

- Needing to be connected to the network drive where jars are stored (and thus, very often needing to be connected to the corporate VPN);
- Or, in the case of jars being checked into the repository, having massive, unwieldy repositories to manage, typically resulting in many duplications of the same jars across different repositories;
- Having no simple, universal and reliable way to (a) know what a dependency's version is and more importantly, (b) know whether that version of that dependency is compatible with all of the other jars in the application's dependency graph.

Maven, Gradle and Ivy are not a silver bullet for all dependency management issues, and naturally they come with their own complexity and learning curve. However, when given a choice, the vast majority of modern Java application developers agree that the benefits of using transitive dependency management outweigh their costs.

We hope that we've struck the right balance in our approach to guiding users how to consume Spring artifacts. We've shone the spotlight on what we (and most folks) consider to be best practices with dependency management by advertising Maven and Gradle syntax, but we've left the door to all comers by by continuing to publish distribution zips. We are however paying attention to feedback to make sure that this approach is in fact suitable for the majority of our users.

For additional information on this topic, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Downloading-Spring-artifacts.

And as a final note, we sometimes hear from folks that they need distribution zips because their company disallows access to public Maven repositories such as Maven Central (http://search.maven.org) or the Spring Repository (http://repo.spring.io). This is completely understandable, but the appropriate response to these constraints is not to keep development teams in the unproductive dark ages of manual dependency management. The correct solution is to stand up a private artifact repository within the corporate firewall. The leading contenders in this product space are JFrog's Artifactory and Sonatype's Nexus. We strongly recommend that any development team still forced into manual dependency management lobby their architecture teams to look into these products and adopt one of them. The benefits to productivity, build reproducibility, and indeed the ability for companies to effectively govern dependencies are dramatic.

Comment: Thank you for adding the alternative.  I work in an environment where there is no internet access on the system that I develop on.  I will definitely be looking into Artifactory and Nexus

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Maven config, go to any Maven repo, and download the JARs from there.  For instance:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Tells me to look in /org/springframework/spring-context/4.0.0.RELEASE folder under any Maven 2 Repository.  Using the example, I [found this](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C-989653419).  You should be able to get all the JARs from there.

Comment: So, yes, spring is trying to stamp out ant developers. :(

Comment: now they even offer a download link anymore? time to move on and look for smth new ...

Comment: Maven still has a good following, but Graddle seems to be were the buzz is at.  I think Graddle has some ability to call Ant (I know it does Maven, as I have had to look at the POM file it generates), so you could use Graddle for dependencies and Ant for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the dependency information for [Spring 4 here](http://mavendependency.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core/4.0.0.RELEASE)

From there you can download the binary jar and the jar with sources for manual dependency management.

Answer (score 0):

I found two sources: the official download page [here](http://repo.spring.io/libs-release/org/springframework/spring/) and [OLEX](http://olex.openlogic.com/packages/spring/4.0.2).

This was after wasting lots of time trying to find the zip files via searches on the Spring site.  There are no longer any direct download links there.